# Make wordpress page as a view in codeigniter

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to make a wordpress page as a view in codeigniter? Right now I have codeigniter and wordpress installed in the root directory. What I want to achieve is to make use of my header, sidebar and footer in codeigniter while I show the wordpress page as the content. Any way I can do this?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-code-igniter/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261051/loading-codeigniter-view-on-wordpress

Comment: Tried installing it but this is what i got when i tried to run mu homepage:

Comment: Warning: require(/system/core/Common.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/mquiambao/PHP Projects/gatorff-dev/faq/wp-content/plugins/wp-code-igniter/ci_mods/CodeIgniter.php on line 52

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/system/core/Common.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.5/lib/php') in /Users/mquiambao/PHP Projects/gatorff-dev/faq/wp-content/plugins/wp-code-igniter/ci_mods/CodeIgniter.php on line 52